# AMD Catalyst Control Center Displaying Unknown Discrete Graphics Card

Tags: ati, graphics, hybrid-graphics, gpu

I have a HP Pavilion g6 - 2301AX laptop. It has an A8 APU with AMD Radeon HD 7640 + 7670M Dual graphics. I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and after installing latest AMD Catalyst, in the "Display Manager" section is showing my 7670M as

> -. [Unknown Display] AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series

Also in the information tab, Control center is showing only the 7640 Integrated Graphics, and not the 7670M GPU. How should I install my 7670M card? I followed the [BinaryDriverHowTo/AMD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD), but I can see only 7640.

Comment: Finnly some with 1 rep, who can wright right!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same graphics card and using samsung laptop. You have to purge the current install drivers. Visit amd support center and by manually providing input select like among desktop and notebook etc, select among the graphics card series like 7xxxm and 8xxxm. Then download it and extract it. Then go to the file saying .run. then go to its properties and under permission check "allow executing file as program". save it. then double click and follow the instruction to install it as you would installing it on windows. Finish it. Reboot. Ta-da. you are done. Now there is one problem. While switching between graphics you have to reboot your pc. 7640 g will give u power saving and go easy on battery backup, while for gaming you can use the 7670m. But 7670M drains the battery lot faster.

Comment: Whenever I enter the details about my laptop [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download), I'm redirected to install AMD catalyst. I have already installed the latest AMD catalyst driver.